# Are there any special horses besides the Dark Brotherhood horse?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I like the Dark Brotherhood horse because it is strong, fast, has a lot of hp, regenerates health fast, climbs mountains, and teleports with you when you fast travel.

Is there another horse in the game with similar attributes that I could get if I don't want to do the Dark Brotherhood quest line?

My boyfriend stole a regular horse once, but it died really fast so I've never bothered with regular horses.

Comment: Afaik all horses are the same (except for skin). they can all climb mountains and travel with you if you fast travel

Comment: My horse can tank and survive a dragon, but dies within a few hits from a bear. :/

Comment: [Look at my horse, my horse is amazing...](http://www.weebls-stuff.com/songs/Amazing+Horse/)

Comment: I read 'special forces' and now all I can think about is the Special Horses Special Forces.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is one - his name is Frost, and he belongs to Maven Black-Briar.

He *is* the only horse with a pedigree (his father is listed as [Sleipnir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleipnir), so take that as you will). If you hang around Riften, you will be approached by a guy who wants you to steal Frost for him. After doing so, you can decide to keep the horse by yourself (though you need to kill / intimidate the quest giver if you want to do that).

That said, he's a totally average horse otherwise. Barring console command chicanery, he's just the same as all the other non-essential horses.

Comment: So.... he dies really fast?

Comment: @Rachel No faster or slower than any Other horse. But to be definitive: only Shadowmere is *superior* to a horse you could grab at any stable near a city.

Answer (score 3):

No, Frost is better than others but is worse than Shadowmere.

Here's a table with comparative:

http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Horse_%28Skyrim%29

and this one too:

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Horses

Answer (score 3):

If you have Dawnguard DLC you can obtain a spell to summon [Arvak](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Arvak), an undead horse.  The spell will last until you dismount.  You can cast the spell whenever you need a horse.

And of course Dragonborn DLC lets you ride dragons.